# I feel that this sentence has a missing word?

Tags: american-english

I feel that this sentence has a missing word. Am I right?

> Eating a healthy diet may take some getting used to, but it has many benefits for your health.

I think it must be

> take some time getting used to

Comment: You're being vague about your question. Do you feel like there should be an _it_ after _getting used to_?

Comment: @Færd I edited the above sentece

Comment: Ah, then no. "_Something takes (some) getting used to_" is an idiomatic expression, and it doesn't lack _time_ (although it's possible to add that too). Look at _(some) getting used to_ as the object of the verb _take_; it roughly means it requires you to get used to it.

Comment: http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/it+takes+getting+used+to  - https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/take%20some%20getting%20used%20to

Comment: @Færd:   ok, thanks. I found your answer persuasive.

Comment: The way it makes sense to me is to take *getting used to* as a thing; then it can take *some of it*, [a lot of it](http://www.azlyrics.com/lyrics/chicago/hardhabittobreak.html) or [a bit of it](http://www.londonlanguagelab.com/phrase-of-the-day-take-a-bit-of-getting-used-to/).